# Icon does not rotate when toggle

Tags: html, css

With PURE CSS I am trying to expand and close a button. It works so far well, but my icon does not rotate 90 degrees how I like it. Why not and how to fix?
Also what I cannot figure out is that when after clicking to expand and clicking back on the button, it does not close. But when you click outside the button area then it does close, why and how to fix?

```css
.expand .icon-right {
    position: relative;
}

.expand:focus+.explain {
    display: block;
}

.expand:active+.explain {
  display: none;
}

.expand:focus > .fas fa-caret-right {
    transition: .3s transform ease-in-out;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.explain {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.explain p {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="q">
           <button class="expand"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i>yes or no</button>
                <div class="explain"><p>whatever you say</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share proper snippet

Comment: @AhmedAli - sorry, added now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector `.fas fa-caret-right` matches a class `.fas` with an element `fa-caret-right` inside. You should use a custom class or `.fa-caret-right` instead.

That is the reason that it was not working at all. For the transition from the focused to the unfocused state you need to set the `transition` property for the unfocused state.

```
.fa-caret-right {
    transition: .3s transform ease-in-out;
}
```

The closing with a second click did not work, because it is still focused. You can use

```
.expand:focus {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

to make the button not clickable when it is focused so it will lose focus when you "click" on it

```css
.expand .icon-right {
    position: relative;
}

.expand:focus+.explain {
    display: block;
}

.fa-caret-right {
    transition: .3s transform ease-in-out;
}

.expand:focus > .fa-caret-right {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.expand:focus {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.explain {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.explain p {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="q">
           <button class="expand"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i>yes or no</button>
                <div class="explain"><p>whatever you say</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have extra space here `.expand:focus > .fas .fa-caret-right`

Try this ..

```
.expand:focus > .fas.fa-caret-right {
    transition: .3s transform ease-in-out;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```css
.expand .icon-right {
    position: relative;
}

.expand:focus+.explain {
    display: block;
}

.expand:focus > .fas.fa-caret-right {
    transition: .3s transform ease-in-out;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.explain {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.explain p {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="q">
           <button class="expand"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i>yes or no</button>
                <div class="explain"><p>whatever you say</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Rju I hope this solve your problem without introducing new css class.